# Boolean method using contentprovider always returns true?

Tags: java, android, string

I have the following method for checking whether an input String already existed in database:

```
public boolean check(String s){
        boolean t = false;
         ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();  
         Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(FTagsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,  
                 new String []{FTagsContentProvider.COL_TEXT}, FTagsContentProvider.COL_TEXT + "=?", new String[]{s}, null);  
         if(cursor != null){
             t = true;
         }
         else{
             t = false;
         }
         cursor.close();
        return t;
        }
```

But no matter I input a new String or a String already existed, this method always return "true".

Was it a problem with the code or could it be a problem with the contentprovider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if cursor.getCount() > 0. Do not check for null. The cursor can be empty and not null.

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
         t = true;
} else{
         t = false;
}
```